# PIC24F: RPINR0 register

Tags: pic, interrupts

Im new to PIC. Im working on PIC24FJ64GA002 PIC. Can any one pls explain how below code says "set RP10 to external interrupt"?

```
                   `RPINR0  =   0x0A00;`
```

I have gone through "PERIPHERAL PIN SELECT REGISTER MAP" from datasheet, RPINR0 register  didnt mention RP10. RPOR5 has mentioned RP10 only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the PIC24FJ64GA004 Family Reference Manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39881e.pdf)

> 10.4.3.1      Input Mapping
>   The inputs of the Peripheral Pin Select options are
>   mapped on the basis of the peripheral; that is, a control
>   register associated with a peripheral dictates the pin it
>   will be mapped to. The RPINRx registers are used to
>   configure peripheral input mapping (see 
>   Register 10-1
>   through 
>   Register 10-14
>   ). Each register contains two
>   sets of 5-bit fields, with each set associated with one of
>   the pin-selectable peripherals. Programming a given
>   peripheral’s bit field with an appropriate 5-bit value
>   maps the RPn pin with that value to that peripheral. For
>   any given device, the valid range of values for any of
>   the bit fields corresponds to the maximum number of
>   Peripheral Pin Selections supported by the device.

`RPINR0` is the input control register for External Interrupt 1 (INT 1).  `PRINR0` is a 16 bit register, with bits 8 to 12 actually implemented.  Those 5 bits controls which pin can drive External Interrupt 1.

Here's the register definition from the family reference manual.

[image]

The desired pin number gets written to the register.  For example, if I wanted to map RP1 to External Interrupt 1 (INT1), I would do this:

`RPINR0 = 0x0100`.

This will assign the decimal value of `1` to the top byte of the `RPINR0` of the special function register, which will map the `RP1` pin to the External Interrupt 1 (INT1) module.

Assuming INT1 is configured correctly in your case, when some external device wiggles `RP10`, the hardware will trigger the `INT1` interrupt, at which point the firmware can decide what to do with it through an interrupt service routine.